# Why do some songs change while fading out? What is it called?

Tags: composition, terminology, pop-music

I noticed that some songs repeat a theme and then fade out at the end, but before completely fading out the song "changes". For example, the singer sings different words (that don't appear in any other part of the lyrics), or his pitch is different.

You can barely hear this change while the song is fading out, but I find that it gives you the feeling of "missing out", that "there is more", and it makes you want to listen to the song again.

Here's an example: [Dennis Edwards ft. Siedah Garrett - Don't Look Any Further](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CH3rx8LhrQo). At 3:50 the song starts fading out, and then at 3:56 Dennis Edwards starts singing something like "tonight we're gonna take you to the para...". Those words don't even appear in the lyrics you can find on the web.

Is there a word that defines this effect/stylistic choice? Is it true that it makes the listener want to listen to the song again?

(I'm not expert at all about music, I'm sorry if I didn't use the correct terms)

Comment: I don't know what it's called, but I think you already answered your own question. Making changes keeps the song more interesting even during a fade-out.

Comment: It used to just be noted as "ad lib to fade". So many times you'd think it was right before a really interesting bit, but it may equally be just before the band gave up & ground to a halt… or the phone rang… https://soundcloud.com/graham-lee-15/unexpurgated-ending-from-life-on-mars (with swearing;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Now that you said it, I've actually seen "ad lib to fade". Make that an answer. But I'd turn the question around: why do they fade out when things finally start to get interesting. ;)

Comment: Reminds me of the original version of Libertango on its premier album, which has the bassist continue soloing while the piece fades out.